# Jest Test on Stencil Component does not apply changes in variables

Tags: jestjs, stenciljs

I want to test a stencil component and configure a global variable in my test like this:

```
describe('my-component', () => {
  const myVarMock = 1;

  let page;
  let shadowRoot: ShadowRoot;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    page = await newSpecPage({
      components: [MyComponent],
      html: `<my-component></my-component>`,
      supportsShadowDom: true,
      autoApplyChanges: true
    });
    shadowRoot = page.root.shadowRoot;
  });


  it('should test', () => {
    page.rootInstance.myVar= myVarMock;
    page.rootInstance.componentWillLoad();
    page.rootInstance.render();

    console.log(shadowRoot.innerHTML.toString());
    const buttonElement = shadowRoot.querySelector('.my-button'); //is null because shadow root is empty
  });
});
```

My Component only renders something, when myVar is set. In the console.log of my test, shadowRoot is always empty, although I explicitly call render() in the test and when I go through the render function in debug-mode it has a value for myVar and renders everything. But why is shadowRoot then empty and my buttonElement is undefined?

Component:

```
@Component({
  tag: 'my-component',
  shadow: true,
})
export class MyComponent{

  public myVar;

  componentWillLoad() {
    ...
  }

    render() {
        return (
          <Host>
            {this.myVar? (
                 <div class="my-button"></div>
             ): null}
          </Host>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Calling those life-cycle hooks like `componentWillLoad` and `render` manually does not do what I think you're expecting it to do. The Stencil runtime calls `render` and uses the return value (JSX) to eventually render your component. Manually calling `render` does not render or re-render your component. In fact, it doesn't do anything except returning some JSX to you but you're not doing anything with the return value.

I think the main issue in your case is that `myVar` is not declared as a property with the `@Prop()` decorator. So even though you have marked your class member as `public` and are able to change it from the outside, Stencil will not wire up anything for you regarding that prop. See https://stenciljs.com/docs/properties.

Instead, you'll have to define it as:

```js
@Prop() myVar?: number;
```

That way it will cause Stencil to re-render your component every time you update the prop's value.

Your test case should just look like

```js
it('should test', () => {
    page.root.myVar = myVarMock;

    console.log(shadowRoot.innerHTML.toString());
    const buttonElement = shadowRoot.querySelector('.my-button');

    expect(buttonElement).not.toBeNull();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the additional information. It sounds logically and I changed it to `@Prop` and removed the function calls, but buttonElement is still null. I also tried `@State` - same effect.

Comment: are you doing anything to `myVar` in `componentWillLoad()`?